# Mapping timestamp in hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am new to hibernate, and in my project I need to insert date and time into a column of type TIMESTAMP. PFB the entity class.

private Timestamp curdate;

```
@Column(name = "UCM_DATE")
public Timestamp getCurdate() {
    return curdate;
}

public void setCurdate(Timestamp curdate) {
    this.curdate = curdate;
}
```

I am getting the following error when i try to run the code, even without providing values to the above field.
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use java Date type like this:

```
@Column(name = "UCM_DATE")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
public Date getCurdate() {
    return curdate;
}
```